# Cannot install or uninstall software

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I’ve been trying to remove some software on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS machine and have been receiving errors like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 356 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.14.0-1038-oem
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=53828a0a-2523-4597-b0e3-3ae0138fc4e9)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.14.0-1038-oem with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am unable to install or remove any software. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like your boot partition is full. You will need to make space on there in order to install updates. After that, you will be able to install and uninstall applications again.

Comment: You're also behind on security fixes too if your details are correct; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ will show the ISO release date of 20.04.5, where installed systems received it in the weeks before that ISO release date too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try to install. Make sure you are connected to internet.